# International Driver's Permit Thailand

Tags: driving-licenses

Is it possible to get an international driver's permit after visiting Thailand? If so how can I get one?

Comment: What country issued your driver license? Do you still live in that country?

Comment: My license issue in Sri Lanka and  Im currently living in Sri Lanka

Answer (score 4):

Whether you visit Thailand or not has no impact on your ability to get an international driver's license.

You can only get one though in the country that issued your actual license since the IDP is actually simply an official multilingual translation of your usual license. That is why it is issued where you got your regular license from since they are the ones to recognize its authenticity.

After you visit Thailand and are back in your home country, you can get the IDP. Here in Canada it is done on the spot, so you can have one within an hour.